# Python os.system() command not working (Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6/2.7)

Tags: python, ubuntu, os.system

I'm trying to run the following commands in Ubuntu 16.04, but I get the following errors. It works fine on Windows, but I don't understand why it fails to work on Ubuntu. I've tried with both Python 3.6 and Python 2.7.

Commands:

```
import os
os.system("del file1.txt")
```

Error message:

```
sh: 1: del: not found
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try running the command on Ubuntu from command prompt?

Comment: `del` is a Windows thing.

Comment: it's not `del` it's `rm`

Comment: You want `os.remove()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

del is not a command in ubuntu. You can choose to use

```
 os.remove('/home/x')
```

File x be deleted from /home path

```
os.remove('x')
```

File x be deleted from current working directory